# Is the framing of the sentence wrong?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrases

So I was guiding a user to perform a task on his browser.
However I feel that the construction of the sentence is wrong:

> "Could you select the URL , by clicking on the address bar and scroll
> to the extreme right "

Is it right or is there a better way of saying it ?

Comment: by ING for both.

Answer (score 2):

From a technical writing viewpoint, here's one way of doing it. The advantages here are brevity and clarity.

Select the URL by doing the following:

- Click on the address bar.
- Scroll to the extreme right.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to suggest a better construction for this kind of task independent of the context. Are you looking over their shoulder? Providing phone support?

I think shorter sentences are better in this kind of situation. One step at a time. Get confirmation before moving on.

> Can you select the url?
>
> How do I do that?
>
> Move your mouse to the address bar.
>
> Done. Now what?
>
> Scroll all the way to the  right, and click.

Comment: Phone support . I am getting an idea , why people get angry over giving phone support !!:D